# newTrigger from Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

In an appscript bound to `FormApp`, I'm trying to add a `onFormSubmit` trigger on the spreadsheet configured as destination of the form, but I neither see spreadsheet as event source from the 'Resources' menu (in script editor) nor can get `.newTrigger` working programmatically.

When `Script.newTrigger('myFunc').forSpreadsheet(sheetId).onSubmit()` is added in function bound to a menu item (when menu item is clicked), this `.newTrigger` call seems to be successful, but without any effect.

I can't see the new trigger anywhere in the script editor (through 'Resources' menu), and when the form is submitted, `myFunc` is not fired. Checking `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length`, it's still 0.

Is any way to do that? Is it a known limitation (not mentioned clearly in the doc btw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a function like this one :

```
function test(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger('testFunction')
   .forSpreadsheet('1xDOaoSl_______0sFz96PIO6iVF4')
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();
}
```

in a Form, the trigger will be in the Form script editor resource and it will call a function that **belongs to the Form script project**, not to the SS script editor.

That function will be triggered when the designated spreadsheet receives a form ( this form or another btw...if the spreadsheet receives data from more than one Form).

Hoping it's more clear now.

[image]

Comment: Was missing the ending `.create()`. Now it appears in triggers list. Thanks. Have to understand why I don't either see log statement or immediate configured notification from this trigger now.